# jQuery.Deferred Exception in Production (Everything fine in dev)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mdbootstrap

For some reason, after pushing an update today to production, I am getting a jQuery.Deferred exception.

This is not the case in my local dev environment.

Using Rails 5.2.2

This particular error is due to MDBoostrap DataTable() function

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

In dev environment, everything is good.

Any help/explanation is highly appreciated!

I reverted back to the original commit and pushed that to production but the issue still persisted. Not too sure whats going on.

Comment: The problem is not with Deferred, Either you haven't loaded the `DataTable` widget, or you've loaded multiple copies of jQuery.

Comment: I guess it would most likely be the multiple copies of jQuery, so this wouldn't affect the local copy? I will have to hunt down to see where this may be happening

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I had to add an explicit //= require directive, in application.js, to add the js file. This is very strange as I am not sure what changed. It was working just fine before the latest push.